# custom ListView drawable does not work with EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I implemented a custom listview with each listview item containing a textview and edittext. The functionality I am trying to implement is when state_pressed the background of the entire listview row will change colour and revert to original colour when not state_pressed.

So far, I have found out that if my listview item does not contain an edittext element, upon state_pressed my listview item will change it's background colour.

After adding an edittext element into the listview item, the state_pressed code that changes the background colour does not work anymore. Where am I going wrong?

My ListView XML

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

ListView item inflated in adapter

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"

android:background="@drawable/selector_listview"
android:stretchColumns="0">

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"

        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

//works without this part -----> start    
<EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"

        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:gravity="center" />
//----> end
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

selector_listview.xml

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/listview_normal"
    android:state_pressed="false" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/listview_state_pressed"
    android:state_pressed="true" />

</selector>
```

listview_normal.xml

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid
    android:color="@color/White" />

</shape>
```

listview_state_pressed.xml

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid
    android:color="@color/Orange" />

</shape>
```

Comment: `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" ` goes in the ListView's row not in the `ListView` itself. Also what is the content of  `edittext`'s drawable

Comment: corrected that! thank you! the problem still persist though

Comment: may I ask you why you want to change the background of the whole `ListView` and not just the background's color of the pressed row?

Comment: uh you are right. I am simply trying to just change the pressed row's background color. (adjusted my question)

Comment: but then `android:background="@drawable/edittext"` should be `android:background="@drawable/selector_listview"`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @drawable/edittext contains the drawings for my edittext element. if I change it to selector_listview, it will only effect on the edittext element and not the entire listview row

Comment: you are right, I didn't see you had the background in layout's root. Btw, why a TableLayout and not a Linear or Relative Layout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72754/discussion-between-user776914-and-blackbelt).

Comment: Since the Edittext receives Ontouch and focus you could try setting the all view Clickable property to false ie android:clickable="false" except the rootview.

Comment: @vignesh It didn't work even when I  set clickable to false for both textview and edittext